# Scala Lift - Mongodb findall with values less than

Tags: json, scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following query:

```
var room "test"
var stamp = 1323339612

recording_model = Recording.findAll(

    ("room" -> room) ~ ("time" -> stamp),
    ("fulltime" -> 1),
    Limit(1)

)
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of matching the time field to stamp, to find all records where time is less than the value of stamp.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
recording_model = Recording.findAll(
    ("room" -> room) ~ ("time" -> ("$lte"-> stamp)),
    ("fulltime" -> 1),
    Limit(1)
)
```